# Present user location swift

Tags: swift, geolocation, location

I'm new to Swift, I want to show user location on map, I added `MKMapView`, and added an outlet, here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController ,CLLocationManagerDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
    let manager = CLLocationManager()

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

        let location = locations[0]

        let span: MKCoordinateSpan = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01,0.01)
        let myLocation:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(location.coordinate.latitude, location.coordinate.longitude)
        let region:MKCoordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMake(myLocation, span)
        map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
        self.map.showsUserLocation = true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

But when I run the app on the simulator it shows me some other location on the USA. But I'm from another place that is not even close to the USA.

Comment: Do you run it on your simulator on the computer?

Comment: Your code is correct if you build your app on a real device. But you need to set your location for simulator. In simulator top menu, select Debug, then find Location section and set a custom location

Comment: @HastiRanjkesh ok thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine, that's because you run it on simulator,  select Debug-->Simulate Location-->Choose some other location and you will see that location on the screen

Answer (score 1):

Because simulator use fake location for testing purpose. you can also change that location See in the image(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GN7x.png).
If you run on actual device it shows your current location.